# Build and Deploy a UI5-App to the Cloud without WebIDE

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

Is there a Best Practice to Upload HTML5 Applications from a File without using the WebIDE.

My Goal is to create a Zip Package which I can deploy to multiple Subaccounts and just needs the proper Destination to get the App running.

**Approach**

- "Build"->"Build Project" in WebIDE
- exported the whole Projectfolder (with dist, webapp, .che...) via WebIDE into a Zip File
- in the Cloud Platform I used "Import from File"

[image: Import from File function in SCP]

**Problem**

- The App wont start
- not able to see the Destinations from Neo-app.json

[image: Destinations in HTML5 App]

Comment: Can you confirmation the destination exists in your other sub-accounts. You can export and import destination details in a similar manner to the above. Destinations appear, to me anyway, to be specific to subaccounts

Comment: The neo-app.json has to be in your dist folder.

Comment: The Destination exists in that Sub Account.

Comment: I didnt touch the dist folder this was all generated. And it contains the neo-app.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to use a [Multi Target Applications (MTA)](https://help.sap.com/viewer/58746c584026430a890170ac4d87d03b/Cloud/en-US/ba7dd5a47b7a4858a652d15f9673c28d.html).

This MTA can be deployed as a "Solution" (and not as a HTML5 app) to your SCP environment.

Your project needs a new file `mta.yaml` where some configuration is done.

You need to download the [MTA Archive Builder](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#cloud) and run the following command to get an .mtar file:

```
java -jar $MTA_BUILDER_HOME/mta_archive_builder.jar --mtar deploy.mtar --build-target=NEO build
```

You can then deploy this solution to your SCP accounts.

[image]

This can also be done via CMD using the [SAP Cloud Platform Neo Environment SDK](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#cloud) and the following command.

```
neo.sh deploy-mta -a "$SCP_ACCOUNT" -u "$SCP_USER" -p "$SCP_PASSWORD" -h hana.ondemand.com --source deploy.mtar --synchronous
```

Read more about creating MTAs [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/05/18/deploy-mta-app-on-neo-starting-from-the-sap-web-ide/).

There is also a [docker image](https://github.com/Cyclenerd/scp-tools-gitlab) which contains all the tools. This can be used for a CI/CD pipeline in Gitlab.

---

Edit: The MTA Archive Builder is deprecated. [Cloud MTA Build Tool](https://sap.github.io/cloud-mta-build-tool/) is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same issue, when i deploy my application in in HCP, the required destination is empty,even if the neo-app.json is correctly configured, and the application is correctly running locally.
I managed to resolve the issue, by deleting the **ui5.yaml** which is generated during the creation of Fiori element project.than I deployed my application on the HCP and application destination is now correctly set on required destination table.